# New to Xubuntu, Confused about the trash bin

Tags: xubuntu, trash

I sent a few files to the trash bin from my second harddrive. I then did a complete reinstall of xubuntu with everything wiped clean on my main drive. To my suprise the contents of the trash bin were still there. Am I correct in assuming its because those files in the trash bin are from the second hard drive.

I apologise if my english is not perfect, not my native language.

Comment: There is a chance the second drive didn't get reformatted so all the content was still there as it wasn't touched. So yes you are correct they are from the second drive

Comment: Each HDD, in fact, any external device gets its own trash.

Answer (score 3):

The trash bin stores files in the device they were deleted from.

If you press Ctrl + H in your File manager, you'll see `.Trash-1000` directory on each partition.

So you are correct. If you format one drive, thrashed files will be kept on another device.